# Неправильный вывод лабиринта

Tags: c, процедурная-генерация

Здравствуйте! Сейчас пытаюсь писать рогалик на си, но, пока что, не могу даже лабиринт отрисовать. Есть такой код:

```
void draw_region_on(struct Region reg, char* field)
{
    if(reg.left != NULL && reg.right != NULL) 
    {
        draw_region_on(*reg.left, field);
        draw_region_on(*reg.right, field);
    }

    else
    {
        for(int x=reg.x; x<reg.w+reg.x; x++)
            for(int y=reg.y; y<reg.h+reg.y; y++)
            {
                if((x>=reg.room->x && x<=reg.room->x+reg.room->w) &&
                   (y>=reg.room->y && y<=reg.room->y+reg.room->h))
                {
                    field[x+y*reg.w] = '.';
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Эта функция рисует заданный регион (часть лабиринта) на массиве символов.

Алгоритм генерации лабиринта такой:
Изначально есть регион, занимающий собой все пространство. Дальше он начинает делится (вертикально или горизонтально) пополам, а каждая его часть, в свою очередь, может либо также разделится, либо создать в себе комнату.

Генерация останавливается, когда размер следующей комнаты должен был бы быть меньше минимального.

Получается примерно такая картинка (вывод перенаправлен в .txt, который открыт в хроме).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно было бы сказать, что неправильно работает сама генерация.

Но, если попытаться вывести тот же самый лабиринт в html:

```
void draw_region_on(struct Region reg, char* field)
{
    if(reg.left != NULL && reg.right != NULL) 
    {
        draw_region_on(*reg.left, field);
        draw_region_on(*reg.right, field);
    }

    else
    {
        struct Region r = *reg.room; 
        printf("<div style=\"position:absolute;top:%dpx;left:%dpx;width:%dpx;height:%dpx\"></div>\n", reg.room->x, reg.room->y, reg.room->w, reg.room->h);
        for(int x=reg.x; x<reg.w+reg.x; x++)
            for(int y=reg.y; y<reg.h+reg.y; y++)
            {
                if((x>=reg.room->x && x<=reg.room->x+reg.room->w) &&
                   (y>=reg.room->y && y<=reg.room->y+reg.room->h))
                {
                    field[x+y*reg.w] = '.';
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Картинка (для того же лабиринта) получается значительно больше похожей на правду:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могли бы вы помочь исправить функцию `draw_region_on`?

Comment: Вы как будто пытаетесь нарисовать графический лабиринт. Хотя на деле движение в играх происходит по графу. И алгоритмы для поиска пути тоже требуют данных о местности в виде графа. Попробуйте сгенерировать граф маршрутов по квадратной сетке. Всё вокруг маршрутов станет стенкой.

Comment: При отладке лабиринтов вам 100% понадобится проверять связность — возможность дойти из точки А в точку Б. (Иначе в рогалике будут непроходимые уровни). Проверять связность вы будете именно с помощью алгоритмов поиска пути.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, Мне кажется, что значительно проще двигаться в плоскости из стен и пола. Хотя, по сути, это одно и тоже: клетка пола - узел, между клетками с общей стороной есть связь. Вопрос не в этом: при любом внутреннем представлении уровень нужно как-то рисовать. Именно это пока и не удается.